# Wordpress get_image_tag filter - change image attributes?

Tags: wordpress

Greetings,
We can edit image attributes with this get_image_tag filter when we are adding images,but is there any similar filter or action that can we use to edit these attributes when post is added or edited - updated?

Here is the link I found.

http://www.webtechwise.com/wordpress-filter-examples-changing-attributes-when-adding-images-to-posts/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please click the checkbox if my answer was helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use `image_send_to_editor`.

Comment: thank you, I jus saw this, I had found an answer already.Thank you for response.